# PHP cURL couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl, port

I am integrating the Pay4Later (a finance company) API into OpenCart.  Part of their API requires data to be posted from the OpenCart server over to their servers using a POST request.

I have this code here, however whenever I try make a request I get: `couldn't connect to host`

Here is my code (I changed some post parameter in the example below):

```
$url="https://test.pay4later.com:3343/";
$post=Array(
    'cr_id'=>'cr_id',
    'api_key'=>'MY_API_KEY',
    "new_state"=>"fulfilled",
    'fulfilment_ref'=>'01234'
);
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,180);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
$status=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curl_response=curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo '<br/>'.$status;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I have triple checked with my hosting company that port 3343 is open for outgoing and incoming requests.

I am totally stumped here.  Does anyone have any advice?

Is there a way to test if the port is definitely open?

Peter

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I can't see any problems in your code. I suggest you use another program(eg. browser) to send the request and see if it works or not.

Comment: @yaccz turning what on and off?

Comment: @AgreeOrNot switching browsers won't make a difference as this is a server-side issue, not a client (browser) side issue.

Comment: @peter No. My suggestion is, instead of using your server, you use another program on your local machine to send the post request and see if it connects or not.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood! I can't use another server because P4L only allow certain IPs to connect to their API service. My IP won't have access.

Comment: However, I could try at least make a connection! Perhaps their IP restrictions only restrict my IP from performing actions, not connecting!  I'll give that a go!